# Changing the Parent View Controller's Background Color

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, viewcontroller

I need to change the background color of a parent view controller in a flipside view controller. I use the following code to do this, which works fine in the iOS 4.3 Simulator, however, the background color **will not change in the iOS 5.1 Simulator.** What changed in iOS 5?

```
-(IBAction)red {
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}
```

Comment: Check if `parentViewController` property is not deprecated. Cos in iOS5 courses I've heard that view (or cild mvc) knows nothing about it's controller

Comment: I am not sure, but Apple added in iOS 5 UIAppearance which may help you: 

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to use self.presentingViewController in iOS 5. (Note that this property is not available pre iOS 5).

Another option, assuming that your delegate is the presenting view controller, would be to change the backgroundColor through a delegate method.